# Objective C error [__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

i m writing an tableView based application. All works perfectly when i use default cells in my tableView. When i try to make customs cells i have this error :

```
2014-12-01 22:50:01.690 Signaturegourmande[15701:624637] -[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb0000000000000c3
2014-12-01 22:50:01.716 Signaturegourmande[15701:624637] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb0000000000000c3'
```

The Application works when i have this code :

```
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [nomData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
```

I have the error when i replace the code with this :

```
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"ProduitCell";
    ProduitCell *cell = (ProduitCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ProduitCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    cell.nameLabel.text = [nomData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.thumbnailImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[urlData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.priceLabel.text = [prixData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
```

I have created a class "ProduitCell" with the ".h" and ".m", i have 3 property in my .h file. i have linked these property in my storyBoard with the right cells items in my Xib.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well the error essentially states that something that you expected to be a `NSString` is actually an `NSNumber` (judging from the `length` message). Based on the two snippets and provided that the first works ok, I would doublecheck the `[prixData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`...

Comment: Ditto to what @Alladinian said, but I'd also check `[urlData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]`

Comment: @LyndseyScott Nice catch, I missed that one :P

Comment: thank you Alladinian and Lyndsey Scott. I checked and that was prixData !

Comment: If you look at the exception stack trace you will see that at the point of failure you're passing an NSNumber instead of an NSString.

Comment: (And if you had actually looked at what the message was saying this would be obvious.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the below line, if it is `NSNumber` class type then change it below by using [stringValue](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSNumber/stringValue):-

```
cell.priceLabel.text = [[prixData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]stringValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

i made it with :

```
cell.priceLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[prixData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

Thanks.